# Replacing only part of the file name in Powershell

Tags: powershell, replace

I got a problem with powershell and some pdfs names

So there is a bunch of them:

```
2021_01_21_Aneks_nr2.pdf
2021_11_31_Aneks_nr3.pdf
2021_05_04_Aneks_nr4.pdf
```

I need to replace "_" with "-" but only near date.
Output should look like this:

```
2021-05-04_Aneks_nr4.pdf
```

I'm new to programming and couldn't find solution in internet.
I was using this code :

```
Get-Childitem | foreach { rename item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_","-") }
```

But it works on all "_" so I cant use it in this scenario.

Thanks for help! :)

Comment: Use `-replace '(?<=\d)_(?=\d)','-'`

Answer (score 3):

Using the `-replace` operator instead of the dot net method you can use regex. And there you can specify to replace only underlines between digits:

```
Get-ChildItem |
ForEach-Object {
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $($_.Name -replace '(?<=\d)_(?=\d)', '-')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
#Loop through files
get-childitem [path] | ForEach-Object {
    #match pattern
    $null = $_.name -match '\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}'
    #get matching pattern
    $pattern = $matches[0]
    #replace _ with -
    $replace = $pattern -replace '_','-'
    #build new name
    $newName = $_.name -replace $pattern,$replace
    #rename file
    rename-item -Path $_.fullname -NewName $newName
}
```

It matches the current name of the file for the pattern `'\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}'`, gets the matching string, replaces _ with - and finally build the new name by replacing the matching string with the updated version.